# Deselect a collectionview cell button when another cell button is selected

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

When I select a collection view cell button then another cell button will be deselected.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FeedHot", for: indexPath) as! FeedHotRightNowCollectionViewCell
cell.playView.tag = indexPath.row
cell.playView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hotRightNowPlay(_:)), for: .touchDown)
}
```

Cell button clicked

```
@objc func hottestOftheWeekPlay(_ sender: UIButton){

    if  GlobalVariable.isAudioPlaying {

    let img = UIImage(named: "icPanelPause.png")
    sender.setImage(img, for: .normal)
    }else{
    let img = UIImage(named: "icPanelPlay.png")
    sender.setImage(img, for: .normal)
    }
    GlobalVariable.isAudioPlaying.toggle()

}
```

Note: Inside didSelectItemAt/didDeselectItemAt cell button click not working.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            if collectionView == self.feedRightNowCollectionView{

           let selectedCell: FeedHotRightNowCollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! FeedHotRightNowCollectionViewCell
           selectedCell.playView.isSelected = true
 }
```

Another Note: I have multiple collection view. Better understand check screenshot

[image]

Comment: call manually inside the didSelectItemAt function. it is not going to call automatically as per your code

Answer (score 0):

call hottestOftheWeekPlay() manually inside the didSelectItemAt function.

like this :

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            if collectionView == self.feedRightNowCollectionView{

           let selectedCell: FeedHotRightNowCollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! FeedHotRightNowCollectionViewCell
           selectedCell.playView.isSelected = true
           hottestOftheWeekPlay(selectedCell.playView)
 }
```

Comment: When I click in UIButton not calling didSelectItemAt.

Comment: at a time only one action is perform it may be didSelectItemAt or button action, both are not going to call.

Comment: yes, button action calling all the time. I am trying to remove
cell.playView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(hotRightNowPlay(_:)), for: .touchDown)
calling but then also not calling didSelectItemAt

Comment: set cell.playView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false and then try

Comment: I have another click event on the image view and button click event different work

Comment: Can you please share the apple document where it is? I already searching but not found a reliable source for this.

Comment: didSelectItemAt is not calling because touchEvent observed by image view.

Comment: Yes, brother I also know that and that is not my question hope so you will understand when you read and see screenshot in my question before . Is there any other way to solve play, pause button preview synchronize.